# Select second element by custom data/attirbute

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

OK. I'm trying to get elements in javascript by CSS selector. To get one by custom element I know is like 'element[custom-name="Literal name"]'.
OK. This works. But now I need to get the second one. I mean I have some elements with the exact custom-name, and for everyone I need to apply a diferent rule (tehere are only 5).

How can I select the other ones? Is posibble select them by CSS?

PS: They are located in random positions, so maybe the first one is the 5 element one time and if I refresh the page it can be the 10 element inside the container.

PS2: No, It's not possible to change the HTML in my case :( . The only code I'm alowed to change is CSS and javascript.

Thanks for reading me! :D

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/exLo5f8o/ and replace the selector with your custom one

Comment: Do you mean the HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can't select specific ones by another, non-order-dependent factor, you can use **the pseudo-selector [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)**. In your case, the complete CSS selector would be `element[custom-name="Literal name"]:nth-child(2)` - substitute the `2` for any other number as you see fit. Generally it's not the best idea to select only by position in the document, as position may change more often than attributes - but in any case, there's a pure CSS solution!

Note that this only works if the elements you're working with are the *only* children of a common parent element - if you're looking for the second element that matches that query in general across the entire document, there is **no way to do that with a CSS selector**. Instead, you can make sure to add a **unique class or other differentiating attribute** to each element, or simply **use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** - in that case, you could get the second element using this little snippet: `document.querySelectorAll('element[custom-name="Literal name"]')[1]`.

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunelly it does not work. It doesnt select the element. Does :nth-child work in that case? I mean, putting first the custom-value... I've never seen that before.

Comment: @about_robots Updated the answer - `:nth-child` may not work at all depending on the structure of your HTML.

Comment: It's one more step to do in Javascript, but works like a charm. Thank you so much. +1 :D